no accessMode defined DV nor on StorageProfile for my-storageclass StorageClass
I am creating a Plans for virtualization on my OKD with vCenter, I have created a StorageClass and a PersitentVolume before create migration plan. But the data volume return no accessMode defined DV nor on StorageProfile for my-storageclass StorageClass although I already put accessMode in PersitentVolume. How can I bind the access mode in storage class file?
Thanks
Here are mine yaml files:
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-storageclass
  uid: d55ea4c6-8d36-4bdf-80be-a4c05e593bed
  resourceVersion: '7017323'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-10-25T07:08:46Z'
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: 'true'
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2024-10-25T07:09:44Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class': {}
        'f:provisioner': {}
        'f:reclaimPolicy': {}
        'f:volumeBindingMode': {}
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-pv
  uid: 19fc8545-9bf7-4f0d-9b22-db4f3249ef9b
  resourceVersion: '7017736'
  creationTimestamp: '2024-10-25T07:10:33Z'
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  managedFields:
    - manager: Mozilla
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2024-10-25T07:10:33Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:spec':
          'f:accessModes': {}
          'f:capacity':
            .: {}
            'f:storage': {}
          'f:nfs':
            .: {}
            'f:path': {}
            'f:server': {}
          'f:persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy': {}
          'f:storageClassName': {}
          'f:volumeMode': {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2024-10-25T07:10:33Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:phase': {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  nfs:
    server: 172.17.0.2
    path: /tmp
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: test-storageclass
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Available
  lastPhaseTransitionTime: '2024-10-25T07:10:33Z'


Try to check the affliated StorageProfile (kubectl get stoageprofile), the access mode is chosen there

Hello, sry for late reply, I  checked the storageprofile and the accessmode is ReadWriteMany
